# How to implement the animation of particles when they collide with the ground?

Tags: animation, particles, collision

I'm not quite sure if this is the right place to write this post (I apologize in advance), but I need some help. I need to do something similar to what is shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTuL_-S0egQ) (03:25). How do I animate an object when it collides with the ground?

Comment: First of all, you cannot do this with particles in Blender. This seems to me like a job for the new simulation nodes in _Geometry Nodes_. But this is not a simple answer which can be given here, this requires some quite complex setups and understanding of what you are doing. Cartesian Caramel's Youtube channel has a lot about that, unfortunately I do not find the video I have in mind, but something similar for example you can find here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FZlDPV22E4

Comment: This is the right place, to ask but while files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: You could make the plant grow randomly on the background, but make sure that they grow at the good location on the foreground, but as Gordon says, there is no automatic way to do it